# Microsoft example for installing Azure extension always gives error Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: azure, azure-cli2

```
az vm extension set \
```

--resource-group QuickstartAnsible-rg 
--vm-name QuickstartAnsible-vm 
--name customScript 
--publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions 
--version 2.1 
--settings '{"fileUris":["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-ansible-control-machine/master/configure-ansible-centos.sh"]}' 
--protected-settings '{"commandToExecute": "./configure-ansible-centos.sh"}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this error when it runs on PowerShell ISE, but it works on the Bash environment on WSL.

On PowerShell, you could enclose codes in **double-quotes** like this.

```
az vm extension set --resource-group "nancytest" --vm-name "ubun-a" --name "customScript" --publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions" --version 2.1 --settings "{'fileUris':['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-ansible-control-machine/master/configure-ansible-centos.sh']}" --protected-settings "{'commandToExecute':'./configure-ansible-centos.sh'}"
```

On PowerShell
[image]

On Bash
[image]